# I want to give access to other group members to my clients directory

Tags: centos, permissions

I want to create a directory under `/google/new` and the owner of the directory must be my client `sara`.

The red group members `nikhil`, `edwin`, `elizwa` must be able to access all the files inside the directory. And all the files to be created inside the directory must have the same group as the directory `/google/new` have.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is a "red group member"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have adequate privileges and `/google` directory exists (if not you need to pass `-p` option to `mkdir`):

```
mkdir /google/new
chown sara:red /google/new
chmod g+s /google/new
```

All the files created inside `/google/new` will be owned by group `red`

Since it's not clear from your question if user `sara` is a member of `red` group, here's also an addition in case that `sara` doesn't belong to `red` group:

```
setfacl -m g:red:r /google/new
```

This will allow users from `red` group to read files in `/google/new`

In that case you'll also want to modify the 2nd line from previous code to correspond to sara's group:

```
chown sara:saras_group /google/new
```